# How to check expression depends on symbol in a particular way

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

Consider these two expressions:

```
expr1 = a d g[X, c]^2 + e g[X, f] + 3

expr2 = a d g[X, c]^2 + e X + 3
```

How do I check whether these expressions depend on `X` only as `g[X, _]`.  More specifically, I want to check that any occurrence of `X` in a given expression must appear as the first argument of the two-variable function `g`, and no other way.

In the two examples above, `expr1` satisfies this criteria,  `expr2` does not.

Right now I can think of only one way to check this:

```
myCheck[expr_] := FreeQ[expr /. g[X, _] :> OK, X];
```

Then, `myCheck[expr1]` yields `True` and `myCheck[expr2]` yields false.  Are there any other ways -- ideally ones that traverse the expression only once?  `myCheck` above traverses the expression twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expr1 = a d g[X, c]^2 + e g[X, f] + 3;
expr2 = a d g[X, c]^2 + e X + 3;

myCheck[expr_] := 
 Catch[ReplaceAll[expr, {g[X, _] -> OK, X :> Throw[False]}];
  True] (* Carl Woll's *)

testQ[expr_] := FreeQ[expr /. g[X, _] :> 1, X]
```

Comparing `testQ` with `myCheck`

```
n = 100000;

Do[testQ /@ {exp1, expr2}, n] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.635065, Null} *)

Do[myCheck /@ {exp1, expr2}, n] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.882478, Null} *)
```

The results might change for more complicated expressions.

Comment: I did the same benchmark on much more complicated expressions, and remarkably, the original one I proposed is faster than @CarlWoll 's .   I wonder what's slowing down his method given that it goes through the expression once.  Perhaps `Throw` and `Catch` are slow things?  Any ideas?

Comment: @QuantumDot - I don't know; presumably overhead associated with `Throw` and `Catch` outweighs advantage of single pass.

Comment: Maybe checking twice whether every sub-expression matches some pattern is not much worse than checking once whether they match one of the two patterns? Anyhow, I have undeleted my proposal (which does not use `Throw`) so that you could check its performance (and verify whether `Throw` was guilty of lowering performance) on your complicated expressions. I would be grateful if you inform about results.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to traverse the expression tree once, then you could do:

```
myCheck[expr_] := Catch[
    ReplaceAll[expr, {g[X,_]->OK, X:>Throw[False]}];
    True
]
```

Your examples:

```
myCheck[expr1]
myCheck[expr2]
```

> True
>
> False

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
myCheck[expr_] := Module[{iDontLikeYou=0},
expr/.{g[X,a_]-> whatever, X :>(iDontLikeYou++;X)};
iDontLikeYou === 0]
```

?
Alternatively you could play with `Abort[]` or `Return[False]` (or something like that) instead of `iDontLikeYou++` to stop evaluation immediately after first wrongly placed `X` is hit.